# Tooling API: Fetch sObject details of Process builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, tooling-api

I know we can fetch Active Version and latest version details using Tooling API from FlowDefinition, however is there a way we can fetch sObject details?

```
'/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,ActiveVersion.VersionNumber,LatestVersion.VersionNumber,DeveloperName+From+FlowDefinition+ORDER+BY+DeveloperName'
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I hope you can help me here. How do we get sObject name in the query?

Answer (score 0):

**You can only get sObject details if you add an `Id = 'flowId'` to your query in the Tooling API or call the `/tooling/flow/flowId` endpoint.**

The info is in the [Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) of the flow which you can only pull when you get one record. You'd have to query all process builders (*Process Type = 'Workflow'*) and then get the info for each specific process builder returned to get the sObject label with `/tooling/flow/flowId` or, if you have the Ids, query with a `Id = flowId` for each flow (or combine into one [composite request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_composite.htm)).

I simplified what comes back in the "Metadata" portion of the response to only include the `processMeatadataValues` you'd be interested in. It's under the "ObjectType" `name` and contains the label in `stringValue`

```
 "Metadata" : {
"processMetadataValues" : [ {
      "name" : "ObjectType",
      "value" : {
        "booleanValue" : null,
        "dateTimeValue" : null,
        "dateValue" : null,
        "elementReference" : null,
        "numberValue" : null,
        "stringValue" : "Account"
      }
    }],
}
```

[image]